The error-rate in "The elements of statistical learning"
This picture is from the book "the elements of statistical learning":

I am wondering how the test-error rate is calculated based on how the describe the simulation at the start? How do they for example calculate the error-rate for the regression when there is no $\beta$?

can you clarify your question? as described the error rate is proportion of misclassified data points (out of total datapoints)

@seanv507 What I do not understand is how we decide if blue or orange is supposed to be the correct one. For example, lets say we observe blue, how do we decide if it was supposed to be blue or orange there?

its not deterministic - for a given x  it may be  probability 60% orange and 40% blue. eg people aged 40 might vote 60% republican and 40% democrat.

@seanv507 Thank you for your answer. And in that case if it is 60 % for orange and 40 % for blue, if we observe orange we label it as correct, and if we observe blue we label it as incorrect?

no if we generated a sample that was blue then blue is the correct answer whether or not its 60% orange

@seanv507 I apologize for beeing slow, but I do not quite understand this. You are saying if we simulate and we get an x which is blue, then we label it blue for that x? But what is it then that decides then if this leads to a 1 or a 0 when we calculate the error rate?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Error rate is calculated as the number of errors divided by the number of attempts. This equals one minus the proportion classified correctly (accuracy expressed as a decimal or fraction).

Thank you very much. But for a given x, how do we determine if it is blue or orange that is supposed to be the correct observation? I mean, we have a way of simulating blue or orange, but what decides for a given x, if blue or orange is the correct observation?
